# PHP Array checking for duplicate value

Tags: php, arrays

```
foreach ($data as $id => $row) {
            foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
                if (array_key_exists($key, $aliases)) {
                    $key = $aliases[$key];
                    $data[$id][$key] = $value;
                }
```

The Array is created above. Within this loop, how would I check for duplicate values for this field... $data[$id]['name']

I have tried something like this inside the for loop

```
if ($value['name'] == $data[$id]['name']) {
    if ($key != $id) {
    "Duplicate Detected"
    }
}
```

Cheers, Laz

Comment: You need to show initial array. You need to also show what you expect as an output

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the $key, and all you are intending to do is know whether that key is already in use; you could do:

```
foreach ($data as $id => $row) {
            foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
                if (array_key_exists($key, $aliases)) {
                    $key = $aliases[$key];
                    if (!isset($data[$id][$key])) {
                        $data[$id][$key] = $value;
                    }
                }
```